# why the Attachements are visible for all recipients even the linked documents are not

Tags: docusignapi, attachment

normaly just who has access to the document with the attachement tag can see the attachement.

and this work well in docusign sandbox but in prod entérinement   the Attachements are visible by all recipients even the linked documents are not visible for them but they can see all attachements

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is controlled under Sending Settings > Append attachments to the document with the attachment field. If that option is unchecked, the Signer Attachment gets added as a separate document. If it is checked, it will be appended to the related document, and Document Visibility should be applied.

[image: Sending Settings screenshot with "Append attachments to the document with the attachment field" highlighted]

Comment: this option is already coched but the Attachment gets added as a separate document

Answer (score -1):

Attachments become part of the document. They're added in the end, like adding more documents. Who can see them depends on many things. The document visibility, the recipients order, etc.
But the general rule is - if you can see the envelope, you can see all the documents in that envelope, including the attachments.

Comment: the Strange Is , the document is not visible for no signer, but the attachement Inside Is visible ,  is that normal ?

Comment: that is a bit unusual, how do you send the document? how many signers? who adds the attachment?

Comment: I used a template which contains 6 documents with 4 signers
 , document number 3 is not visible to the first 2 signers and it has an attachment field , documents attached by siganteur number 3 are visible to everyone but not the document itself

Comment: let me ask one of the support engineers to look into this. That's a complex scenario and I'm not sure if you're encountering a bug or there's something else that is unclear.

Comment: documents (A, B, C, D) ,signers (S1,S2,S3,S4)
A contains Attachment field T1
C contains Attachment field T2

S1 sign (A, D), S2 sign (B), S3 sign (A, C), S4 sign (A, B, C, D)

S1 sign A, D and attach T1 => ok
S2 sign B and not see A but can see T1 => not ok
S3 sign (A, C) and attach T2 => ok
S4 sign (A, B, C, D) andd see T1, T2 => ok
  realization email:
            S1 recois (A, C, D) + T1, T2 not ok normaly just T1
            S2 recois (B) + T1, T2 not ok normaly no attachment
            S3 receive (A, C) + T1, T2 ok
            S1 receive (A, C, D) + T1, T2 ok

Comment: can you give us the envelopeID?

Comment: 6bab5f2b-bde2-476a-8133-088afe802419

Comment: Hello Ahmed, from what I'm hearing it sounds like Signers are able to view attachments from documents that are hidden from them, is that correct? Specifically, Signer 2 is not able to see Document A, but is able to see an attachment to it? I've found an internal issue report that aligns with what you're seeing. Please open a case from https://support.docusign.com, link this post and reference issue number SIGN-28432.